# Is it practical to record table creation/modificaion events in a separate table?

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, database-design

I'm about to begin designing a database for an MVC web app and am considering using a table called 'changes' or 'events' to keep track of all changes made to the database. It would have a field for the table name, record id, user making the change, the timestamp and whether it was a creation or modification event.

My question is whether this is a poor design practice compared to having 'created by', 'created on', 'modified by', 'modified on' fields in each table. I was thinking that in the parent Model class, I would use a before-save function recorded every change. I can see a pitfall might be if many records were updated at once, it might be difficult to get the function to save the changes properly.

Comment: The key to answering this question is "*What do you hope to get from it?*"

Comment: If you do this, you need to do it through triggers and not through the application so you capture all possible changes to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of weighing up the benefit of having the granular info against the overhead of writing to this table every time something in the database changes and the additional storage required.

If you are concerned about using a function on the model class then an alternative would be database triggers. This would be quite robust, but would be more work to set up as you would need to define triggers for each table unless the database you are using has a facility to log DML changes generically.

Finally, I would also advise considering archiving as this table has the potential to get very big very quickly.

Comment: I didn't realize that was possible, but using database triggers sounds like a great approach. That will give me an opportunity to broaden my understanding of databases too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is fine.  One advantage of having these events in a separate table is you can capture *multiple* edits.  If you just have `ModifiedDate/ModifiedBy` columns you only see the *last* edit.

The main thing to be aware of is table size since audit tables can get VERY big.  You may also decide to split into *multiple* audit tables (e.g. use the same table name with an `_audit` suffix) to improve query performance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need.  The reason for creating and maintaining an events table is to maintain an audit trail of changes.

For some applications, the created / updated fields at the end of a row are a sufficient audit trail.

For more secure applications, you need an events table.  You also need to include the actual change (before / after) in your events table.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider a time-related table, where each record has a start and end date, along with a created by. Any change actually sets the end date for the previous record and creates a new record, with a NULL end date.

Your current record is the one with a NULL end date.

Basically, every record has a life-span.